# Block "Complete action using" chooser from launching

Tags: android, android-intent

Whenever the user does an action that multiple apps can support, they are prompted with the "Complete action using" popup asking them to choose an app. For security purposes, I don't want this chooser to popup at all and instead force open the action within the app.

Is there a single place in my project where I can set all intents to only open activities within my project?

Comment: If you know what activity you want the intent to open, just use the class name to send the intent.

Comment: My problem is when using classes like Linkify, it creates URLS that can be opened in other apps. Since I don't have access to the source in Linkify, I cannot set the package name for the intent.

Comment: Oh, well in that case the answer is no. If you're using classes that create their own Intents, you can't control what they do to that extent. You could extend `Linkify` and override the behaviour, though.

Answer (score 0):

> Since I don't have access to the source in Linkify, I cannot set the package name for the intent.

Either don't use `Linkify` and set up [the `ClickableSpan` objects](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) yourself, or replace the spans created by `Linkify` with your own `ClickableSpan` objects.